# Wordpress Options FollowSymLinks error

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, plesk

I have a website setup in my /httpdocs directory with it's own htaccess and I have a wordpress blog within /httpdocs/blog, using the standard wordpress htaccess

I keep seeing the following error in my apache error log:

[error] [client #.#.#.#] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/blog/index.pl

I added "Options +FollowSymLinks" as this seems to have fixed the problem for others (but not me)

The main .htaccess is as follows:

The Wordpress .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPres
```

I am also wondering why the error is reported as "index.pl" since there are no perl scripts in /blog. So, after some searching, I found an httpd.include file (plesk generated) in the /var/www/vhosts/somedomain/conf/ which contains some perl handler stuff:

SetHandler perl-script
   PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
   Options ExecCGI
   allow from all
   PerlSendHeader On

If I remove perl support via Plesk, thus removing the above block of code, then I don't get errors anymore.

The obvious answer would be to disable perl as I don't need it, however there must be a way to fix this error without having to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

add to .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

all done :)

Comment: Ah, just had to remove the + to make it inherit! Thanks Vovan

Comment: dude, make me some +1 rating :)

Comment: Done (and same for my question...) :)